# Ghostscript: gs command not found (Windows10, gs9540w64)

Tags: php, google-sheets, command, ghostscript

I wanted to use Ghostscript to work with some PDF files, so I successfully installed Ghostscript 9.54.0 for Windows (64 bit) (Ghostscript AGPL Release).

After that I successfully added the bin and lib folders to my PATH variable:

```
 PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
 C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;[.........];C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.54.0\bin;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.54.0\lib;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

But when I try to run a Ghostscript command (from a php file) I get this error:

> "gs" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
> programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Which means that gs isn't recognized as an internal/external command...

I also tried to add bin and lib to PATH installing the Ghostscript 9.54.0 for Windows (32 bit) version, but I get the same error.

Does anyone have a clue of what I could be missing? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I've solved it by using gswin32c.exe command instead of gs! In my case:
        gswin32c.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE (...)